# Using booktabs with Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, xtable

Booktabs and xtable fail with Rmarkdown using RStudio. The Tufte template works fine, but using a standard `.Rmd` file fails with the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.133   \toprule

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

A reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Testing booktabs"
author: "r.bot"
date: "11 June 2015"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
options(xtable.booktabs = TRUE)
xtable(head(mtcars[,1:6]), caption = "First rows of mtcars")
```
````

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Latest version of Pandoc installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try including a file `header.tex` in which you depend on the booktabs package.  See [the latex options](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#latex-options) for rmarkdown for details.

*Edit:* While the inclusion of headers is convenient and allows for wider ranging changes, here we get by with the top-level options `tables: true`. So the minimal change for the example above is

```
---
title: "Testing booktabs"
author: "r.bot"
date: "June 11, 2015"
output: pdf_document
tables: true
---
```

after which the sample `xtable` output appears with booktabs.

Comment: Yes, that resolves it, but since pandoc seems to include booktabs anyway, I don't understand why it doesn't work without an external .tex file. https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex
`$if(tables)$
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
$endif$`

Comment: So try enabling option `tables`.

Comment: The documentation on how to do that isn't particularly clear. After a little trial and error I found that 

`output:
  pdf_document
tables: true`

fixes the problem without resorting to an external .tex file.

Comment: Dear @r.bot, the customary way to thank someone who took time read and answer your question is to upvote or accept such answer, not to intrude and edit it without asking. My thanks to pc-shooter for reverting.

Comment: I apologise for having intruded, it was not my intention to offend. I simply wanted to make sure that the full solution was in the answer itself and not the discussion. I'll refrain from doing so in future.

Comment: I'd be happy to edit my answer. I was actually looking for just one of those top-level switches, but didn't see one, knew about he include: solution and had to get out of the house.  We can improve on this (and all this came in handy as were just discussing finer rmarkdown->pdf points as work :)

Comment: Yes, please do edit and I will be happy to accept it. Thanks.